# FullCalendar: Prevent auto-scroll after updating options

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using the Javascript fullcalendar package. After creating a new event, I'm assigning the updating the calendar options `events` property:

`this.calendarOptions.events = this.timeslots`

When I do this, the calendar scrolls the view back up to the initial scrollTime property in the calendar options:

`scrollTime: "08:00:00"`

This happens even if I set the `scrollTime` to null before setting `events`. The created event is then out of view and not visible.

How can I prevent the calendar from autoscrolling?

Comment: Are you using Angular, or React or one of those? If so please tag it appropriately

Answer (score 2):

Turns out Fullcalendar added a `scrollTimeReset` flag just a week ago that prevents auto-scrolling after updating the options: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/scrollTimeReset

Worked nicely for me after upgrading all packages to 5.7.0!

Comment: The issue is scroll goes to top with calendar.refetchEvents() on Version 6.0.3. 

Before 5.7.0 is fine.